# In React, why is a called function containing a closure not immediately run upon component mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

With a typical react function, calling the function within an event (e.g. `onClick={}`) will result in the function being called immediately upon component mount.

For example, this code will fire immediately upon mount because the function is being called:

```js
const App = () => {
  const fn = () => {
    alert("hey");
  };
  return (
      <button onClick={fn()}>click</button>
  );
};
```

However, if the function uses a closure, it will only execute when the button is clicked. For example:

```js
const App = () => {
  const fn = () => {
    return () => alert("hey");
  };
  return (
      <button onClick={fn()}>click</button>
  );
};
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: I don't see any closures. When `fn` gets called another function is returned, you don't call that function. I don't know if this is valid in react but try: `onClick={fn()()}` (the first `()` calls `fn` and the second `()` calles the function returned by `fn`)

Comment: JSX expressions are evaluated at the point they appear in the code, so your `return` statement fully evaluates the `<button>`, including the interpolation in the `{ }`. The expression inside `{ }` is therefore evaluated.

Comment: @ibrahim any function that is returned from within another function creates a closure, as it is able to access all variables in it's scope.

Comment: In both cases, you're running `fn()` when assigning `onClick`, so `fn` is executed when the component renders. The difference is, the first one just calls an alert, whereas the second one _returns a function_ that calls an alert. `onClick` is assigned to the return value of `fn()`, which in the first example is null (since it doesn't return anything) and in the second one is a function.

Comment: @JonasWilms yeah, but I don't see any variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what's going on here it might help to substitute the function call with *what it's evaluating to* (inlining the call). In the first case, it is `undefined`, as the function does not return anything. While evaluating it's value, it also `alert`s, resulting in:

```
 alert("hey"); // this is more or less executed here
 <button onClick={undefined} >
```

In the second case, the function *returns another function*, so that's what it evaluates to:

```
 <button onClick={() => alert("hey")} >
```

Now a function get's passed to `onClick`, which will be called when the button is actually clicked.